# How to detect a php file download with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http-headers

I have to make a file download with php headers

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$equip[1].'-config.txt"');
$downloadable=str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $res['result']);
echo $downloadable;
```

When User clicks on the download button, the form gets a jQuery block ui with a spinning gif, becouse the file generates for long time. Then User get a file, and I need to unblock my form...

Have you any idea for this?

Comment: You need to make it in 2 times : do a simple return for your ajax call, and from the JavaScript side, unlock your form and redirect your user to the downloadable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thx for all of you!

My solution is:

- making a hidden form
- asking data via Ajax then unblock the other form
- putting results to the hidden form with jQuery
- posting the form with jQuery, return the txt

I hope it can help the others who need it! But if you know other better solution, please post it for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea: Can't you make a AJAX Request to get the file? Unblock the form as soon as you recieved the AJAX Response. You'll also get a Status if something went wrong (404, 500, etc...)

EDIT:
Seems like it won't work that way... But can't you request the creation of the document via AJAX and the server responds with the actual URL to download the file..? You could unblock your form directly after you started the download, because the file is already prepared and it won't take much time anymore

Comment: how do you save an ajax request to disk ?

Comment: Hm.. I thought that would be possible... passing the result to a new window or something...